# Supporting multiple screen sizes

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I want to build a mobile application in Delphi, but I can't seem to figure out how to handle multiple screen sizes. AndroidStudio has a nice relative layout for this, but I can't find anything alike for delphi. Am I supposed to build a multiple form designs for each screen size?

I'm using XE6, I am requoired to use Delphi as the programming language.

Comment: Which version of Delphi do you use?  I think that XE8 has some new tooling. AndroidStudio looks like a good option doesn't it.

Comment: I'm using XE6. And I'd prefer to use AndroidStudio, but I'm required to use XE6.

Comment: I re-tagged the question. Version is critically important when it comes to FireMonkey because it is still nascent. Massive differences between different versions.

Comment: XE7 makes this much easier. If you're "required" to use Delphi, then the people who are mandating it should at least have an ongoing support contract to keep up with the new releases, because this is one area that is continuously being improved.

Answer (score 1):

I have already figured it out, you have to use the Align property on every single control you add to the form.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to get familiar with layouts: [FireMonkey Layout strategies](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/FireMonkey_Layouts_Strategies), especially the `TFlowLayout` and `TGridLayout`